# It is possible to set multiple passwords to single login in ubuntu platform?

Tags: user-management

I tried with different ways, but not worked at all. Please any-one help me ?

I've looked at this question:

- [Use one password for administration and another for system login](https://askubuntu.com/questions/258049/set-2-passwords-for-one-user)

The referenced duplicate is not the same question. The referenced question is about how to use one password for normal usage and one for sudo.

This question question can imply that a person has 20 passwords (none of which needs to be sudo)